# HstSiteConfigurer: ComponentManager initialization failed

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, content-management-system, hippocms

**I'm working on One Hippo CMS, when I run the Tomcat server I'm getting this error**

> 5.02.2019 18:23:45 ERROR main [DefaultHstSiteConfigurer.initializeComponentManager:264] HstSiteConfigurer: ComponentManager initialization failed.
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.hippoecm.hst.content.beans.manager.ObjectConverter' defined in class path resource [org/hippoecm/hst/site/container/SpringComponentManager-content-beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Annotated class 'org.example.myproject.beans.Urldemo' for primarytype 'myproject:urldemo' is a duplicate of already registered class 'org.example.myproject.beans.Simple'. You might have configured a bean that does not have a annotation for the jcrType and inherits the jcrType from the bean it extends, resulting in 2 beans with the same jcrType. Correct your beans.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the annotations on:

org.example.myproject.beans.Urldemo
org.example.myproject.beans.Simple

They should each have an annotation similar to:
@Node(jcrType = "project:doctype")

Each needs a unique jcrType value.